# Asantibanez/Livewire-Charts extras.tooltip

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, apexcharts

I am using Asantibanez/Livewire-charts, and I already plotted the chart, the problem is when the number reaches thousand, No comma is displayed, when I tried formatting the number, the Chart displays only the thousands digit. The owner said that it can be done using the extras.tooltip but I don't know how to use it.
Is there anyone here know how to use it?

Edit: here is my stacked column chart

```
$index = 1;

        foreach ($this->patientCountPerHosp as $key => $value) {
            if ($key != 0) {
                foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
                    // dd($this->label[$index])
                    foreach ($this->months as $monthKey => $monthValue) {
                        if ($key2 == $monthValue) {
                            $multiLineChartModel->addSeriesColumn($this->hospitalName[$index], $key2, $value2, [
                                'tooltip' => number_format($value2, 2),
                            ]);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (
                    $index < count($this->hospitalName) - 1
                ) {
                    $index++;
                } else {
                    $index = 0;
                }
            }
            $multiLineChartModel->setColors(array_slice($this->color, 29, 10));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I have figured out your problem, currently tooltip is not compatible with multiColumnChart.
Currently it only supports columnChart, lineChart and PieChart.
Try to use one of those three, if possible, please ask to be added to multiColumnChart or hope to include it in a future update.

Commit v2.5.0 released: https://github.com/asantibanez/livewire-charts/commit/9f9554314eb1c75c0f152f13ee236ee336e966c3

### Example of use

```
$profitMonth = (new ColumnChartModel())->setTitle('Profit month')
        ->addColumn('January', 1587518.87, '#008f39', [
            'tooltip' => '$'.number_format(1587518.87, 2),
        ])
        ->addColumn('February', 3815212.48, '#008f39', [
            'tooltip' => '$'.number_format(3815212.48, 2),
        ])
        ->addColumn('March', 2148538.05, '#008f39', [
            'tooltip' => '$'.number_format(2148538.05, 2),
        ])
        // ->addColumn(...)
        ;
```

Make sure you have the latest version, this way of doing it is available as of version 2.5.0 ([CHANGELOG](https://github.com/asantibanez/livewire-charts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md))

Comment: I tried using it, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version, this way of doing it is available as of version 2.5.0 (https://github.com/asantibanez/livewire-charts/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: I do have the latest version but it doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Let's see it has to work for you, the issue is to see your code to see what is happening, if you update your question and add the controller code and the view we could help you. I encourage you to get it.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question and added how i created the chart